# Does every invertible matrix A has a matrix B such that A=Adj(B)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, adjoint-operators

I'm trying to understand if it's always true, always true over $\mathbb C$ or never true.

I know that if $A$ is invertible, than there exists $A^{-1}$.
$$A=\frac{1}{det (A^{-1})}Adj(A^{-1})$$
So I have an adjoint matrix multiplied by a scalar, but how do I know if the result is an adjoint by itself?

Comment: But is it an $Adj(B)$ of some matrix $B$?

Comment: Hint: [$\operatorname{adj}(\operatorname{adj}(A)) = (\det A)^{n-2} A$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649187/prove-that-if-a-is-regular-then-operatornameadj-operatornameadja?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no solution over $\mathbb R$ if $n \ge 3$ is odd and $\det(A) < 0$.

$\det(\text{adj}(B))= \det(\det(B) B^{-1}) = \det(B)^{n-1}$, which can't be negative in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The case $n=1$ is immediate. For the case $n\ge 2$, by user1551's comment,
$${\rm adj}({\rm adj}{(A)})=(\det A)^{n-2}A.$$
Also, there is a fact that ${\rm adj}(kA)=k^{n-1}{\rm adj}(A)$ for any scalar $k\in\mathbb{C}$. Thus we have
\begin{align}
{\rm adj}((\det A)^{-\frac{n-2}{n-1}}{\rm adj}{(A)})
&=(\det A)^{-(n-2)}{\rm adj}({\rm adj}{(A)})\\
&=(\det A)^{-(n-2)}(\det A)^{n-2}A\\
&=A,
\end{align}
and the result follows by taking $B=(\det A)^{-\frac{n-2}{n-1}}{\rm adj}{(A)}$.

Comment: This solution works over $\mathbb C$.  If $\det(A)$ is negative and $n \ge 3$ is odd, you  won't be able to solve it over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you for your mention.